# Frobenius splitting and smoothness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R\rightarrow S$ be a morphism of rings in characteristic $p$ which is formally smooth.

Is it true that $R$ is Frobenius splitting if and only if $S$ is Frobenius splitting?

One direction seems to be easy but I am not sure if both implications are true.

Comment: I don't recall seeing this in the literature.  Although I'd point out that Frobenius splitting isn't such a good notion in the case of non-$F$-finite rings (ie, rings where the Frobenius is not a finite map).  It might be better to look at $F$-purity.  Do you really want to look at Frobenius splittings?

Comment: @KarlSchwede you can assume $F$-finite if you want. Sorry for my ignorance but why is $F$-purity better in this case? I am interested  in maps coming from geometry. In my situation I have a triangle $X\stackrel{f}{\leftarrow} Z \stackrel{g}{\rightarrow} Y$ of schemes where $f$ and $g$ are formally smooth and $Y$ is Frobenius split. I want deduce weak normality of $X$. If what I asked is true then also $X$ is Frobenius split hence weakly normal.

Comment: $F$-splitting is picking elements in $\Hom_R(F_* R, R)$.  When $F_* R$ is not finitely generated, that $\Hom$ set is badly behaved (say with respect to localization or completion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following.  I'm going to assume that all rings are Noetherian (some things probably generalize, but I want to be careful). First a definition,

**Definition:** An extension of rings $A \subseteq B$ is *pure* if $M \otimes_A A \to M \otimes_A B$ is injective for every $A$-module $M$.  A ring $A$ is called *$F$-pure* if the Frobenius map $F : A \to A$ is pure.  For an $F$-finite ring, being $F$-pure is the same as being split.

Hochtser-Roberts, *The purity of the Frobenius and local cohomology*, Proposition 5.4(b) implies that if $A \to B$ is faithfully flat, then it's pure.  I'm going to then assume that in your case, the ring maps are faithfully flat.

**Theorem:** (Hochster-Roberts, Prop 5.4(a))  *If $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ are rings and $B$ is pure in $C$, then $A$ is pure in $B$ if and only if $A$ is pure in $C$.*

Now suppose that $R \subseteq S$ is faithfully flat (I'm going to assume you can do faithful, as otherwise there isn't any hope).

Ok, so then set $A = R$, $B=S$ and $C = S$ with $B \to C$ being the Frobenius on $S$.  Likewise set $B' = R$ with $R = A \to B'$ being the Frobenius on $R$.  In otherwords we have
$$
A \subseteq B \subseteq C
$$
and
$$
A \subseteq B' \subseteq C
$$
Since $S$ is $F$-pure, $B \to C$ is pure, and so $A \to C$ is pure since $A \to B$ is faithfully flat.  But now certainly $B' \to C$ is also pure (since it is also faithfully flat) and so $A \to B'$ is also pure so that $R = A$ is $F$-pure.

**Conclusion:** *If $S$ is $F$-pure and $R \subseteq S$ is faithfully flat, then $R$ is $F$-pure.*

---

For the other direction, obviously faithful flatness will not be good enough but the following is true.

**Theorem: (Hochster-Huneke?)**  *If $(R, \mathfrak{m}) \subseteq (S, \mathfrak{n})$ is a flat local extension of local rings (say excellent to be safe) such that the closed fiber is regular and $R$ is $F$-pure, then $S$ is $F$-pure.*

Hochster and Huneke proved a harder result (replacing $F$-purity by $F$-regularity in *F-Regularity, Test Elements, and Smooth Base Change* Theorem 7.3 and adding some assumptions about generic fibers which allow one to mess about with test elements, see the theorem on page 171 of [these notes by Hochster](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/711F07/fndtc.pdf))  Their methods will prove the Theorem.  The case you probably want follows directly from the proof of a result of myself and Wenliang Zhang, Lemma 4.5 in *Bertini Theorems for $F$-singularities*, but the above theorem was certainly known long before that by all the experts.

Comment: thank you very much. I have the impression I am missing something. Assume $R\rightarrow S$ is smooth. We have a  factorization $R\rightarrow C:=R[x_1,\dots,x_n]\rightarrow S$ where the second map is étale. Now if $A\rightarrow B$ is étale we have $F_{*}B\cong F_{*}A\otimes_A B$ (standard theorem in étale cohomology), hence if $A$ is split so is $B$. For $R\rightarrow C$, if $R$ is split the same holds for $C$ because we can send $x_i^p$ to $x_i$. So in conclusion if $R$ is split also $S$ split. In this case we don't need Hochster-Huneke. Am I wrong?

Comment: Dear alfs you are right.  The Hochster-Huneke theorem actually holds for maps with *regular* fibers though (not necessarily geometrically regular), so the conclusion is stronger.  Best wishes,